# 14.04 Simple Scan no longer starts, 'segmentation fault' when run in terminal

Tags: 14.04, scanner, scanning, crossover

I can no longer run Simple-scan on 14.04 under kernel 3.13.0-34-generic.

It quits before the UI loads and when I run simple-scan from terminal I get a segmentation fault. It's such a useful tool for me and I'm annoyed because it used to work perfectly. All I have changed recently (other than routine dist-upgrades) was 'dpkg --add-architecture i386' to get the latest version of Crossover running.

Any ideas?

I'm temporarily using 'gscan2pdf' which is ok but really slows down my workflow when compared to Simple Scan.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I should have added xsane 0.998 still works okay for me. The problem is isolated to Simple-scan.

Comment: Same problem here, although `sudo simple-scan` works fine.

Answer (score 11):

What worked for me was:

1. Delete the files in ~/.cache/simple-scan/autosaves/
2. Delete the file ~/.cache/simple-scan/state

Found out the error using `simple-scan -d`.

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: It worked like a charm in my case: `simple-scan` crashed after a scan with too high resolution, and I couldn't re-load it. Deleting temp files did the job.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the `simple-scan` Directory and Files had wrong permissions.
Due to running `simple-scan` first with `sudo`, the Dir and Files had `root:root` rights.

Just change Permissions to your Users Permissions:

```
sudo chown -R myuser:mygrp ~/.cache/simple-scan
```

Comment: You can use the environment variable `$USER` to make the command a kind of universal: `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.cache/simple-scan` (check the result of this command: `echo "$USER"`).